# Estimating population size from relative appearances

Tags: time-series, estimation

I know that widget X has a population of N_x.  However, widget Y has an unknown population that I'd like to estimate.

Both widgets appear with a differential frequency over time as I sample them.

Time ... X counts .... Y counts
1  .......... 120  ............... 2
2  .......... 212  ............... 3
3  .......... 321  ............... 5
4  .......... 149  ............... 0
5  .......... 321  ............... 1

What is the total population of Y?  With what confidence?  I'm particularly interested in any special considerations that I many need to make when Widget Y is much rarer than the reference Widget X.

Best,

Paul

Comment: Are you doing capture -recapture?  What is the relationship between widget Xs coubts and widget Ys counts?  Without more information there seems to be no way to answer this question.

Comment: The populations of widgets X and Y are fixed and are  selected out of a much bigger universe of widget types.  I'm not familiar with capture - recapture.  Can you point me to a tutorial?

Comment: You can Google it and find references I am sure.  This is a common way to estimate the size of a population based on sampling.  Take for example the goldfish in a pond.  You collect a sample of say 20 goldfish.  You tag them and put them back in the pond.  The you sample 20 more and notice how many tagged ones you got back.  This enables you to estimate the total number in the pond by ratios.  20/N  should be about the same proportion as x/20 where x is the number recaptured.

Comment: So the estimate of N=400/x  If x=2 then the estimate for N is 200.  You can continue to tag and replace the fish and collect another sample to improve the estimate.

Comment: Here is a Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to assume that the widgets have the same probability of appearance.

If you have $N_x$ widgets and you sample $n$ from them, the probability that you do not observe one particular widget is $(1-1/N_x)^n$. So the expected total sum of widgets you do not observe is $N_x(1-1/N_x)^n$, and by complementarity the expected total sum that you observe is $N_x - N_x(1-1/N_x)^n = N_x(1 - (1-1/N_x)^n)$.

Because you know $N_x$, in every observation you can use the methods of moments to guess $n$. If I am not mistaken, if you observe $k$ widgets out of $N_x$, that should give you $n = \log(1-k/N_x)/\log(1-1/N_x)$. If you simultaneously observe $m$ widgets out of $N_y$, this is also equal to $n = \log(1-m/N_y)/\log(1-1/N_y)$. After a little bit of math, you end up with $m/N_y = k/N_x + \alpha$, where $\alpha$ depends on $N_y$ weakly if it is small compared to $N_x$.

So this suggests to do a plot of the counts of Y against the counts of X divided by $N_x$ and do a orthogonal regression (equivalent to principal component analysis in this case). The slope will be an estimator of $1/N_y$.

This is a *very* gross approach. In particular, this does not give any estimate of the confidence around the estimate of $N_y$, but this might be a good start.